I created a function to write with Firebase, but there is a problem with implementing the search function
I made a writing function with Firebase, but when I search for the title if it's "ice cream", it comes out when I search for "ice cream", but it doesn't come out when I search for "cream".
I've tried a plug-in called searchflex, but it doesn't work.
I asked about the method I ordered on the Internet and AI, but I can't do what I was told, so I have a question left.


import { db } from './firebaseConfig.js';
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { PostListManager } from './PostListManager.js';

export async function setupSearch() {
    const searchButton = document.getElementById('searchBtn');
    const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    const resultsContainer = document.getElementById('results');

    const postListManager = new PostListManager('results');


    async function loadData() {
        try {
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'posts'));
            const posts = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                id: doc.id,
                ...doc.data()
            }));
            return posts;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error loading data from Firestore:', error);
            return [];
        }
    }

  
    async function performSearch() {
        const searchText = searchInput.value.trim().toLowerCase();
        if (searchText === "") {
            console.log("Empty search text.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            const posts = await loadData();
            const filteredPosts = posts.filter(post => {
                const titleMatch = post.title && post.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
                const descriptionMatch = post.description && post.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
                const contentMatch = post.content && post.content.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
                return titleMatch || descriptionMatch || contentMatch;
            });

            if (filteredPosts.length === 0) {
                console.log('No matching documents found.');
            } else {
                console.log(`Found ${filteredPosts.length} matching documents.`);
            }

            postListManager.renderPosts(filteredPosts, false);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during search:', error);
        }
    }

    // 검색 버튼 클릭 이벤트
    searchButton.addEventListener('click', performSearch);

    // 엔터 키 입력 시 검색 수행
    searchInput.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            performSearch();
        }
    });
}




Along with @alexmamo excellent answer, another approach is to break down sentences into individual words. The sentence "I like ice cream" would be stored as "i", "like" etc. The document that contains the words (perhaps in an array or map) also contain the sentence. When the query is performed and results are received, the returned document will contain the full sentence.

@Jay Hey Jay. Nice solution for the OP's use case. Can you please post it as an answer? I would like to upvote it.

@AlexMamo Thanks and I added an answer. I would also mention that while Firebase doesn't support a partial string query for beginning strings, you can actually do a partial string query for ending strings. In this case, for example, if we wanted all strings staring with "ice" the query parameters could be startingString("ice")...endingString("ice\u{F8FF}". See this answer for  an explanation. (it's Swift but the concept is generic)


I made a writing function with Firebase, but when I search for the title if it's "ice cream", it comes out when I search for "ice cream", but it doesn't come out when I search for "cream".

That's the expected behavior. There is no way you can search in Firestore after a substring. Firestore doesn't support full-text search. Besides that, downloading an entire collection to search for fields client-side isn't practical at all.
Seeing the official documentation regarding full-text search in Firestore, there are three options available by the time I'm answering this question, which are Elastic Search, Algolia, and Typesense.
If you want, you can simplify the process by using the corresponding Firebase Extensions, which are:

Search with Elastic App Search
Search Firestore with Algolia
Search Firestore with Typesense


Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

One option for performing word searches in Firestore is store the original sentence or text as a document property and then break down the sentence or paragraph into individual words and store them in a separate array. Upon querying and finding a match, the document is returned so you can get the original text.
A document could look like this pseudo-document
  sentences
     document_id_0
        original_text: "People of the Earth can you hear me"
        word_array:
             0: "people"
             1: "of"
             2: "the"
             3: "earth"
             4: "can"
             5: "you"
             6: "hear"
             7: "me"

Query the sentences node for documents where word_array using array-contains that contain "earth", which will return document_id_0 (in this case) and the sentence contained in "original_text" property. Storing the words a lower case and querying lower case is advised.
